# How to get the filename and extension out of a URL?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using prototype and trying to get the filename and extension out of a URL in the `src` attribute of an `<img>`. For example, I want to get `colorch091001-black-2.jpg` out of this:

```
<img id="small_img_src" src="http://127.0.0.1/magento162/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x265/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/colorch091001-black-2.jpg">
```

I can get the `src` value with:

```
var img = $('small_img_src').src;
```

But how do I get just the filename and extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, For pure JavaScript Solution

```
<img id="small_img_src" 
     title="Royal Dress" alt="" 
     src="http://127.0.0.1/magento162/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/265x265/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/o/colorch091001-black-2.jpg"
     style="display: block;" />

var src = document.getElementById('small_img_src').src;
alert(src.substring(src.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
```

Comment: yogi, if i want to get the first whole part expect the last part. i using alert(img.substring(0,(img.lastIndexOf('/')-1)); why it doesn't work. thank you

Comment: It depends on what you have in that `img`, Not sure but may be you should try `img.src.subs...`.You could debug your code and see what is there in `img` of which you are trying you `substring`.